# How to create a new feature layer from the selected features?

Tags: arcobjects

I have a simple tool written in ArcObjects which takes features from a layer and does some processing on them.

I use a feature cursor to loop through all the features in the layer. To perform the necessary processing I have written several functions which accept an IFeatureLayer reference.

What I want to achieve is:

- I want to process only those features which are selected
- I don't want to change my code in all my existing functions. So I want to be able to continue to pass an IFeatureLayer reference to these functions.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Query interface/cast from your original [`IFeatureLayer`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureLayer_Interface/0012000004tp000000/) reference to [`IFeatureLayerDefinition`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004v2000000) and call its [`CreateSelectionLayer()`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0012/0012000004v9000000.htm) method.

This will create a new feature layer from the existing feature layer based on its selection and optionally an expression to further filter it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its somehow not working for me completely, Here is the Code:


Sub testing()
'Defined & Set stuff like IMap and ImxDoc
SetEverything

Dim l As IFeatureLayer
Dim fs As IFeatureSelection
Dim newL As IFeatureLayer

Dim ld As IFeatureLayerDefinition
Set l = pMap.layer(0) 'l has 400 records
'Now Selected 1 record in layer l
Set fs = l
Set ld = l

Set newL = ld.CreateSelectionLayer(l.Name & "_1", True, vbNullString, vbNullString)

MsgBox newL.featureClass.FeatureCount(Nothing) 'it prints 400 and NOT 1

end sub

please help. if I add newL in TOC, then it has 1 record